# .htaccess domain slash username to username page php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I get an error. or problem that I would like some help on.
I would like to make it easier for users to go directly to a users profile like how facebook and twitter do. eg: twitter.com/kanyewest. my .htaccess looks like this 
Please assist me on how i can make my redirect similar to twitter, etc.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*(data|tmp|log).*\.php)$
RewriteRule .*$ – [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

My website is set up like www.mydomain.com/u/1

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but try something like this:

```
RewriteRule /([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /u/$1
```

That will send requests for `mydomain.com/username` to `mydomain.com/u/username` without changing the url.