# how to change domain/controller/method/parameter to domain/parameter?

Tags: php, .htaccess

actually i just wanna make this only for 1 controller is `UserController.php`.

```
<?php
    use \application\controllers\MainController;
    class UserController extends MainController{
        function __construct(){
        $this->setsession();
        $this->model('user');
    }
        public function index($username){
            if (!isset($_SESSION['clogin'])){
                $this->template1('index');
          }else{
            $query = $this->user->selectWhere(array('username'=>$username));
             $data = $this->user->getResult($query);
            $this->template2('user', $data);
          }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

according to code above, to access user page i need to go to localhost/web/user/index/username i want change to localhost/web/username. I have try this in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule /([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /user/index/$1
```

base on question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948067/htaccess-domain-slash-username-to-username-page-php), but it's not working. this is the complete code of .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule /([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /user/index/$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does your others rules works ?

Comment: yap, this is someone framework. other rules is work

Comment: Wauw, your complete security is based on the existence of `$_SESSION['clogin']`, that isn't realy secure.

Comment: do you have any suggest? @RonvanderHeijden